# Android Transitions: Go to other scene without animation on orientation change

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have two [Scenes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html) in my layout.

First is the original scene with which the activity view is inflated.

And the other is the scene to which the first is transitioned to using `TransitionManager.go(secondScene);`

Now when the device is rotated, as expected the entire transition is played again. I want to prevent this and want to directly show the second scene. I have all the  data in my savedInstanceState so I know that the activity has been recreated, but I don't know how to directly show the second state without the animation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You gust put null for TransitionSet

```
TransitionManager.go(secondScene, null);
```

or

```
sceneRoot.removeAllViews();
View scene = inflate(getContext(),R.layout.second_scene, null);
sceneRoot.addView(scene);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scene class has an enter method which you can call if you want to move to next scene without any animation:

```
val nextScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, nextSceneLayout, activity)
nextScene.enter()
```